# How come gas burners don't melt?

Tags: gas, propane

A gas burner (torch) that burns mapp gas is advertised to have a flame temperature of 2900 C. Steel melts at 1300 C. Gas burner tips are made of steel. How come they don't melt?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't about home improvement. It's a physics question that might be better asked at http://physics.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the temperature of the hottest part of the flame. Here is a useful picture from SE that shows temperatures for a candle flame:

[image: temperature of candle flame]

Here is a diagram for a gas flame showing how the temperature changes by region. Only the hottest point in the center is at the claimed maximum:

[image]